# Spring's @DateTimeFormat ignores wanted date format pattern

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, datetime-format

Can't get my head on how date formatting using @DateTimeFormat works.
I send query with date params being:

```
dateCreateFrom - 01.04.2022T00%3A00%3A00
dateCreateTo   - 30.04.2022T00%3A00%3A00
```

But at the controller endpoint I get dates like: `2022-04-30T00:00`

Controller looks like:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss")
dateCreateFrom: LocalDateTime? = null,
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss")
dateCreateTo: LocalDateTime? = null,
```

Maybe someone can explain me why I get such results and how can I get results that I want to (dd.MM.yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss)

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

date if milliseconds and 13 digits(hex to date)

```
val dtlong = Date(date)    
val sdfdate = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(dtlong)
```

date if milliseconds and 10 digits(hex to date)

```
val dtlong = Date(date*1000)    
val sdfdate = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(dtlong)
```

string to date

```
val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH)
val mDate = formatter.parse(dateStr)
```

Comment: trying to parse date '2022-04-30T00:00' using formatter like this throws DateTimeParseException
Text '2022-04-01T00:00' could not be parsed at index 2

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/text/SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Are you using Java or Kotlin?

Comment: I'm using Kotlin, I managed to properly parse the date, but question why did I get 2022-04-30T00:00 date in controller when I sent another date format is still relevant

Comment: "dd.MM.yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss"  if you change it like this it will

Comment: val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)

Comment: Can you give an example how do you want to get it?